# Set multiple TextView from different layout

Tags: android, textview, settext

I'm trying to set multiple TextView by calling setText on my TextView from my `MainActivity.java` but I get an error (null object) because (I guess) my setContentView is pointed on `R.id.first_layout` and one of the TextView is in another layout (let's say `R.id.second_layout`).

How could I setText on those 2 differents layout in my MainActivity ?

I tried the following code but nothing change when I launch the app :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View navHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, null);

nameTextView = (TextView) 
navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
nameTextView.setText("Test")
```

Comment: Is `second_layout` the header layout for a `NavigationView` that's in `MainActivity`?

Comment: @MikeM. yes ! I tried to change the info of the header with a setText

Comment: The header takes a some time to actually load into the `View` hierarchy in recent versions, so you have to do things a little differently. The question linked at the top of the page has the options.

Comment: @MikeM. Great, thank you, I'll take a look at the question linked!